# Progress bar in dropzone not working

Tags: jquery, html, dropzone.js

I'm trying to add a progress bar to dropzone.js. When I add file, the progress bar appeared, but when I press the save button, nothing happens. The save button is a custom button to save files, which have been added to the dropezone. This is how I do it

```
$(document).on("click", "#AddLogoForm .btn-save", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (logoDropzone.files.length > 0)
    {
        logoDropzone.processQueue();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#AddLogoForm").submit();
    }
    logoDropzone.on("success", function() {
        location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

This is my HTML-code to add the progress bar

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
</div>
```

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** This is how I call dropzone:

```
function DropzoneInit() {
var previewNode = $("#template");
previewNode[0].id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parent().html();
previewNode.remove();

var logoDropzone = new Dropzone("#AddLogoForm", {
    url: $("#AddLogoForm").attr("action"),
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    maxFiles: 1,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    previewsContainer: "#logopreviews",
    clickable: "#AddLogoForm .dz-input",
    accept: function (file, done) {
        if (file.type != "image/jpeg" && file.type != "image/png" && file.type != "image/gif") {
            done("Error! Files of this type are not accepted");
        }
        else { done(); }
    }
});
```